# Python time series dataframe set an element every cycle in a while loop

Tags: python, dataframe

I am new with python surely I did not the best code but I obtaine almost what i want and I am in the last mile.
 I am trying to fill a dataframe for a time series with frequency of one sec in a while loop with a pause of one sec , inside this loop I am trying to set dataframe element at the time but instead to write in a single element each time i write in all data frame element. 
What I don't understand if I make a test with np.random.randint(0,100,size=(len(rng)) it functions properly but when i insert in place of np my variable it will fill all the dataframe with the last data

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

today=datetime.today()
rng=pd.period_range(today,periods=1000,freq='S')
rng=rng.astype('datetime64[ns]')
df = pd.DataFrame(rng, columns=['date'])

df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df= df.set_index('datetime')
df.drop(['date'], axis=1, inplace=True)

x=0
    while True:    

        try:
        df['data'] = np.random.randint(0,100,size=(len(rng))
        # if instead of np i put my variable data it will fill all the data frame with the last data

        print(x)
        print(df.head(x))
        time.sleep(1)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break
```

Comment: i found this solution: before the while loop I added

Answer (score -1):

i found this solution: before the while loop I added df['data']=np.nan e inside the loop i changed the line with the random number with this df.iloc[x]='my series variable' and x+=1. In easy words i create a dataframe element iteration. I don't know if there is a better way to do it